# website page to change on hover

Tags: html

I feel like this is a stupid question but here goes. Is it possible to have a page change upon hover of menu button? for example if i point my mouse at the about us menu button it would change the page automatically without having to click on? wordpress, html, etc...

Thank in advance.

Comment: This can be done with JavaScript.  Is that an option?  This is also not really user-friendly.

Comment: Change page or just change content?

Comment: say there is 6 menu buttons in total( home, about, contact, etc...) each with own corresponding page, I hover over each page in each menu buttton and the screen changes to that page.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't natural as far as user experience, you can easily accomplish it with Javascript. For example -

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onmouseover = function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
};
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WtG7P/)**

Comment: I don't think that's what he's looking for - hopefully not because that is UX terror.